# Represent an update in an use case diagram

Tags: uml

I'm making an use case diagram for an application. This application while starting up and displaying the splash screen updates new files from a FTP server. Should I represent this in a use case? If so, which should be the actor? I am quite confused.

Comment: You need to elaborate on the domain. Which is the system under consideration? What is it good for. Just a short summary.

Comment: The application is a desktop application for reporting, it takes as input excel files, it downloads them from a FTP server, and on every time the user starts the application, new files added to the server are downloaded.

Comment: Which do you consider to be the primary actor? I guess the user.

Comment: The use case has nothing to do with an application and files touched by it. It's the value the actor draws from it. Can you describe that value? I guess it's something like `Create report`.